# Using pretrained BERT embeddings as input to textcat models in Spacy 3.0

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, spacy-3

I'm trying to shift over to Spacy 3.0's training config file framework and am having trouble adjusting the settings to what I'd like to do. Simply put, I would like to use one of the out of the box textcat models (say, bag of words), but pass in the word embeddings produced by a pretrained transformer (e.g., bert base cased), without any fine tuning. So far I've been working off of the texcat config template provided on the Spacy website.

Any help would be much appreciated. I can provide additional details if necessary. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following config. `-G` switches to a `transformer` and `-o accuracy` switches to the textcat ensemble model:

```sh
spacy init config -p textcat -G -o accuracy config.cfg
```

See: https://spacy.io/api/architectures#TextCatEnsemble

Comment: Thanks for the command! I'm running it without a gpu and it seems to be taking quite a while to train. This would be understandable if it was training the transformer, but I thought it was just using the pretrained model to give me word embeddings to pass into the textcat model. Am I misunderstanding the steps in this pipeline?

Comment: Transformer training without a GPU is going to be unbearably slow and isn't really recommended. If you just want static word embeddings, leave out `-G` and it will use the word embeddings from a pretrained pipeline if available, e.g. for `-l en` it would use the word embeddings from `en_core_web_lg`. Or you can provide your own in a model created with `spacy init vectors`.

Comment: Again, thanks for all the help. I have one last question. If I went the static word embeddings route, I can use the word embeddings from `en_core_web_trf`. But does this also mean I need to add a (in this case, RoBERTa) transformer listener to the textcat component? Currently it has a tok2vec listener because of the nature of Spacy's out of the box textcat ensemble model.

Comment: Transformer embeddings are not static, so it's not a 1-to-1 replacement like this.